Dell Xubuntu close lid shutdown option
Hardware: Dell XPS 7390
OS: Xubuntu 24.04
My main issue is that in the power settings for when the lid is closed, there is no option for shutdown / poweroff.
I've seen a few reports of this but no resolution.
What everyone recommends (and is often the accepted answer) is to add "HandleLidSwitch=poweroff" to /etc/systemd/logind.conf
BUT: In Xubuntu, this seems to be ignored altogether. System always goes into standby when the lid is closed.
So all the lid activity is intercepted by xfce4-power-mananger but it doesn't have the option for poweroff.
How can I get this thing to shut down when I close it?

First step is to put a pin in the timestream with
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp

Then, do your suspend/shutdown thing. When your system is usable again,
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"

This will show you all the log messages since you set pin.tmp. Some messages relate to your problem.
